# Given $a_1$, find an increasing sequence so that $a_1+\dots+a_k $ divides $ a_1^2+\dots+a_k^2$ for all $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, induction

Prove that for every natural number $a_1>1$ there's an infinite series $a_1<a_2<a_3<...$ such that for every natural number $k,$ $a_1+a_2+...+a_k \vert a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_k^2$.

At first glance, I thought this problem is an induction problem and could be solved by forming the sequence inductively. I tried that and didn't get anywhere even though I'm pretty sure there must be an inductive solution.

I went in a different direction, experimenting with series and trying the series
$$a_2=3\cdot a_1$$
$$a_3=3\cdot a_2=9\cdot a_1$$
$$a_4=3\cdot a_3=9\cdot a_2=27\cdot a_1$$
and so on... (esentially every number is three times the number before it in the series)

This way, if we assume the condition stands for $k-2$ and try to prove it for $k-1$ we get
$$a_1\cdot (\frac{3^k-1}{2}) \vert a_1^2\cdot (\frac{9^k-1}{8})$$
From here, we know $a_1 \vert a_1^2$ so we need $\frac{3^k-1}{2} \vert \frac{9^k-1}{8}$, but since $\frac{9^k-1}{8}=\frac{3^{2k}-1}{8}=\frac{(3^k-1)(3^k+1)}{8}=\frac{(3^k-1)}{2}\cdot \frac{(3^k+1)}{4}$, so actually we get that $\frac{3^k-1}{2} \vert \frac{9^k-1}{8}$ if $\frac{(3^k+1)}{4}$ is a whole number. This only works for $k\equiv 1$ (mod 2). I'm not sure where to go from here, I've tried proving this, but for even numbers and haven't gotten anywhere. I'm worried I might be going deep down the series solution rabbithole even though it might not lead anywhere. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Also, what is the $\color{red}{\text{exact wording}}$ of the original problem?

Comment: And you can get a vertically centred and properly spaced ellipsis using `\cdots`,  a properly spaced vertical bar using `\|` and properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Downvoted and voted to close because question lacks details.

Comment: @Cookie FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_1%5Clt%20a_2%5Clt%20a_3%5Clt%5Cldots%5Clt%20a_k%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a_1%2Ba_2%2B%5Cldots%2Ba_k%5Cmid%20a_1%5E2%2Ba_2%5E2%2B%5Cldots%2Ba_k%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Anatural&p=1), almost the same question is asked in the AoPS thread [A Sequence prob.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1544693p9364580), & [$a_{n}$ geometric sequence, prove that : $a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+...+a_{n}\|\ a_{1}^{k}+a_{2}^{k}+a_{2}^{k}+...+a_{n}^{k}$ with $(n,k)=1$](/q/3425526) here has a somewhat related question.

Comment: I apologize for the answer-delete, I thought this question had a more straightforward answer than it did!

Comment: @user2661923 I'm not sure of the source... my professor only told me he found it on AOPS a while ago and I can only presume the link John sent is what he was referring to. I don't have any more details in the task statement given to me, I did, however, translate this from my language to English so I apologize if I've made any errors.

Comment: Also, I'll fix the formatting errors now, I'm sorry.

Comment: I don't understand "voted to close because it lacks details". What details are lacking?

Comment: In answer to your comment/question: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: If it's irrelevant that the problem is homework, why did you mention it at all?  You are the only person to bring it up. And it seems to me that the question does show work; your reply to my question "what details are lacking" is nonresponsive.

Comment: @mjd Good points: [1] There is a lot of confusion around whether homework problems are allowed.  This is why I **always** emphasize that it is irrelevant.  [2] I definitely agree that work is (**now**) shown.  I could be mistaken, but I think that at the time of my comment, that work had not been shown.  So, at the time of my comment, unless I am mistaken, my comment was on point.

Comment: The only changes made to the original post were in the title and in the change of formatting of the multiplication signs, the work shown has stayed the same. @user2661923

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're trying to find a strictly increasing set of integers $a_i$, with $a_1 \ge 2$, so for all $k \ge 1$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i \, \mid \, \sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to finish what you've tried. Instead, as you surmised, there's an inductive solution. For $k = 1$, \eqref{eq1A} is true since $a_1 \mid a_1^2$. Assume that, for some $m \ge 1$, \eqref{eq1A} is true is for $k = m$. Set

$$j = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Thus, by \eqref{eq1A}, since $a_1 \ge 2$, we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i^2 = jn, \; \; n \ge 2 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Let

$$a_{m+1} = j(n + j - 1) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Since $n \ge 2$ and $j \ge 2$, then \eqref{eq4A} and \eqref{eq2A} give that $a_{m+1} \gt j \; \; \to \; \; a_{m+1} \gt a_{m}$. Using $k = m + 1$ in \eqref{eq1A}, the LHS becomes

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}a_i = j + j(n + j - 1) = j(n + j) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

The RHS of \eqref{eq1A} is then

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}a_i^2 & = jn + [j(n + j - 1)]^2 \\
& = j(n + j\,[(n+j) - 1]^2) \\
& = j(n + j\,[(n+j)^2 - 2(n+j) + 1]) \\
& = j(n + j\,[n+j][n+j-2] + j) \\
& = j(n+j)[1 + j(n+j-2)]
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

From \eqref{eq5A}, the LHS divides the RHS of \eqref{eq1A}, so it's true also for $k = m + 1$. Thus, by induction, we have \eqref{eq1A} is true for all $k \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using a sequence with $a_k = 3 a_{k-1}$ seems to work when $a_1$ is even, though the proof doesn't go through.  Try writing an explicit formula for $a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_k$ and for $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_k^2$ - both are geometric series - and then divide one by the other.

When $a_1$ is odd, a geometric series with a different ratio (not 3) will work.